# Creating string length function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

> Your task is to write a function called stringLength that accepts a
>   string as a parameter and computes the length of that string; however,
>   as you may have guessed, you are not allowed to use the length
>   property of the string!
>
> Instead, you'll need to make use of the string method called slice.

My program is not creating the right output. Please explain the error in my code.

```
function stringLength(string) {
let start =0;
let end= string.slice(0, "");
let result=0;
for(let i=start; i<=end; i++){
result++;
}
 return result;
}
```

My output is 1

Whereas the output should return the length of the given string.

Comment: What is `slice(0, "")` supposed to do? Btw `[...string].length`

Comment: @JonasWilms i thought it would give the end of the given string, but clearly i was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
function stringLength(string) {

  let index = 0;

  while (string.slice(index) !== '') {
    index++;
  }

  return index;
}
```

*string.slice(index)* will return the substring from character at index *index* until the end of the string. If *index* exceeds the biggest index in the string, it returns an empty string. That's how you know you have to stop counting.

You could even do it without *slice* at all:

```
function stringLength(string) {

    let count = 0;

    for(let char of string) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice can get one parameter for start index and it will slice till the end or two parameters for start index and end index. You can't put "" as a parameter
Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with `''` as parameter, which will return an array with all the letters of the string. Then, just iterate through this array using the method [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), adding 1 to a counter for each letter, like below:

```
function stringLength(string) {
        return string.split('').reduce(function (length) {
            return length + 1;
        }, 0);
}
```

With ES6 syntax, it gets even shorter:

```
function stringLength(string) {
        return string.split('').reduce((length) => length + 1, 0);
}
```